# Can't create action buttons

Tags: android

I am currently trying to learn android programming and have encountered a problem. When I try to complete the Action Bar tutorial it does not work. It runs, but on the Action Bar only the overflow button diplays and that contains the settings button. I have no idea why this does not work. Here is the code:

```
package com.example.usingui;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.usingui.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);

}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

and `res/menu/main.xml` :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Please help me!

Comment: you search action is not displayed in the action bar next to the overflow button?

Comment: yes, but the settings is there in the overflow button

Comment: that's what `yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"` does. use `never` to always display it in the overflow.

Comment: @njzk2 yes but no search button display

Comment: you forgot to add the search button code to your class.  Check out my answer below and replace your entire method onOptionItemSelected

Comment: @Cybergei: the use of the menu in the java code is irrelevant to the question

Comment: do you have several menu/main.xml files for various configurations ?

Comment: njzk2 - What planet are you on.  He specifically asked how to do it.  It is not only exactly relevant but it is the answer.  He needs to make adjustments to his XML to make the button visible and then add the java code for that button in his class.  If it is not relevant, than how about helping this guy out and telling him something valuable that he can use or impose some of your wisdom upon us.....

Comment: I still don't know what to do :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_settings:
            //Do something here
            return true;

        case R.id.action_search:
            //do something here
            return true;



        default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

That is my code for my action bar

Comment: Then you simply add a new case per action button by adding a new `case R.id.action_button:`
`//do something here`
`return true;`

Comment: didn't fix it. I don't know what else to do D:

Answer (score 0):

I see that in your XML for the menu, you have android:showAsAction="never"  change it to always for each menu item that you want to see in the action bar  so it would be this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="always" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Using "never" means that your action button will only be in the overflow menu which is normally the hardware button on the lower left.  "IfRoom" will make adjustment for example if you have 10 action buttons and then go to portrait mode, then it may only show 3 buttons and then throw the rest into the overflow menu.  Use "always" for those buttons that you want to show no matter what in the action bar   :)

Comment: ahh , also you are missing the code for the buttons.  One second

Comment: okay, thanks, I just started learning programming for android :)

Comment: real quick while I get the code answer for you, also try out https://buckysroom.org/videos.php?cat=6  to get a good hold on android.  I love that guy

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true; ->you can handle every item of action bar and you can do any interaction in here!
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I am agree with Cybergei you should set visible of every item of action bar by writing `android:showAsAction="always"` and as I wrote above,you can do anything what you want by handling id of every item inside of the `onOptionsItemSelected` method

Comment: You didn't understand What I mean :),you need to learn "how can you handle id of actionbar item so learn this one firstly by using google :)

Comment: Cybergei wrote what I mean :) look it :)